# Find word match allowing up to n words separation in R

Tags: r, regex

Looking to match word1 before word2, allowing up to 5 word separation between word1 and word2. For example, if word1 is apple and word2 is mango, then pattern should match 'apple is a fruit like mango' but not match 'mango is a fruit like apple' (word2 before word1) or 'apple and orange are fruits, like mango' (longer than 5 words). Example regex in python is `\b(?:word1\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?word2|word2\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?word1)\b`. What is an analogous pattern and function to identify this pattern in R?

Answer (score 1):

```
#DATA
word1 = "apple"
word2 = "mango"
p1 = "apple is a fruit like mango"
p2 = "apple and orange are fruits, like mango"
p3 = "mango is a fruit like apple"

#FUNCTION
foo = function(word1, word2, string){
    ind2 = unlist(gregexpr(word2, string))[1]
    ind1 = unlist(gregexpr(word1, string))[1] 
    nwords = length(unlist(gregexpr(" ", substr(string, ind1, ind2))))
    if(ind2 > ind1 & nwords <= 5){
        substr(string, ind1, ind2 + nchar(word2))
    }else{
        NA
    }
}

#USAGE
foo(word1, word2, p1)
#[1] "apple is a fruit like mango"

foo(word1, word2, p2)
#[1] NA

foo(word1, word2, p3)
#[1] NA
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful in terms of seeing the underlying code structure.

Answer (score 1):

This one works. Counting the first word as apple, this regex searches the next 4 and matches if it finds mango in the defined word limit.

```
library(stringr)
> stri <- c('apple is a fruit like mango','apple and orange are fruits, like mango','apple is not a fruit like orange or mango')
> stri_extract_all(str = stri, regex = 'apple(\\s\\w+){1,4}?.mango')

[[1]]
[1] "apple is a fruit like mango"

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA
```